# I would have liked vs I would like

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between:

> " I'm short, I would have liked to be taller."
>
> " I'm short, I would like to be taller. "

Answer (score 1):

Ummmm, The difference is a matter of timing

We use would like to have + -ed form when talking about things in the past that we have missed, in your sentence " i would have liked to be taller " maybe i think i will not be taller because i have reached puberty , etc "

on the other hand , " i would like to be taller " this implies maybe i haven't reached my puberty yet and i want to be taller at this time.

i hope it helps

Comment: When writing an answer, it's important to use proper capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: i am sorry , but i don't know the rules for using " punctuation " properly , so i avoid using it

Answer (score 0):

It can be used to state differences in timing, but usually it's used to express the feeling of inevitability, and usually has an implied, "but it'll never happen," paired with it.

Examples:

I would have liked to be an astronaut, but since I only have one arm and no legs, it's not really an option.

I would have liked to be taller, but I'm 85 years old and I'm pretty sure I'm done growing.

"I would have liked to see the sun rise one more time," said the man facing the firing squad.

On the other hand, using "I would like" implies that there is something you can do to get the thing you want.

"I would like icecream," he said to the icecream salesman.

"I would like to be taller," he said to the doctor.